# BreezeJS script creates global variables

Tags: javascript, breeze

I use breeze "1.4.11" version. This happens in the following code blocks. It seems that the 'var' is missed:

```
...

function clone(that, propName, value) {
    ...

    // Global variable 'copy'
    copy = __extend(new EntityQuery(), that, [

    ...

    return copy;
}

...

function isolateES5Props(proto) {
    ...
    // Global variable 'es5Descriptors'
    es5Descriptors = {};
    stype.getProperties().forEach(function (prop) {
        // Global variable 'propDescr'
        propDescr = getES5PropDescriptor(proto, prop.name);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in both cases for v.1.4.12. Thanks for reporting it.